# Special values for 3D rotations matrices

Tags: matrices, rotations

I wanted to know if there are other "special" angles when using the rotation matrices in 3D. Looking at them I see that if the value of $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = 2\pi$ then the rotation matrices are the identity matrix, therefore vector doesn't change at all.

Are there other "special" values for $\theta$ to consider?

The rotation matrices are as follow:

$$
R_x =
  \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
   0 & \sin \theta  & \cos \theta \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
R_y = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
   \cos \theta & 0 & \sin \theta \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   -\sin \theta & 0 & \cos \theta \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
R_z = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
   \cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 \\[3pt]
   \sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\[3pt]
   0 & 0 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: What's $\theta$?

Comment: The angle of the rotation... Check the update :D

Comment: Well I'd certainly consider $\theta=\pi$ special.  Beyond that, much depends on what you mean by "special".

Comment: Ok, i tried with $\theta=\pi$ and I see it changes the sign in the rotating axes. For instance, making a rotation about $Rx$ of the vector $a(x,y,z)$ transform the vector into $a'(x,-y,-z)$, is this a kind of reflection?    I think we have the same meaning of "special" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me case $\theta=i\pi/2$ where $i=0,1,2,3$ is a special one because it generates matrices with values exclusively $\{-1,0,1\}$. Compositions of these matrices also give matrices with $\{-1,0,1\}$ values  (there are such $24$ cases) so they are good for simple exercises with rotation matrices and for checking different  rotation formulas for example [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula).